# Very weak WiFi signal - 16.04 - Centrino N 2230

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

everyone

I'm having problems with wifi on my dell laptop. I've been updating ubuntu on this laptop since 12.04 without any issues. Everything was working fine, but now I'm having wifi signal issues, I can't connect to my home wifi, only to my phone if I have it placed on the laptop itself. I don't see any of the several Wifi access points of my neighbours that I would normally see.

I've tried restarting the wifi connection and the PC several times without any result. I've also tried some ideas from other threads (modprobe commands, reinstalling linux firmware, restarting network manager) but couldn't make it work.

Here is the info from the wireless info script https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QxY49C8Dbc/

Any idea or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's not enough info, we need the output of your tcp ip dump, there may be a conflict in the background

Comment: Hi, thanks for your commet! How should I obtain that info?